# Git - fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly cause of big size folder

Tags: git, deployment, nuxt.js, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy Nuxt.js static app to github pages with this command: `gh-pages -d dist --dotfiles`

I got error message `error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly`

The problem is with static assets, I have about 400-500MB of images in dist folder, without them git works fine, but when I add this big size folder It's problem. What's the solution please?

Comment: Did you tried hosting it on Netlify or Vercel?

Comment: Git makes a terrible deployment system. (It *can* be used as one, but if you fall outside the relatively narrow parameters of where Git works well, Git will, to put it colloquially, suck <synonym-for-donkey>.)

Comment: The usual solution to this kind of problem is a CDN ("content delivery network", e.g., cloudflare).

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSH instead of HTTPS. You could use git LFS to deal with big static assets, but I have the feeling that will still fail when it needs to pull down those objects. You could move those somewhere else maybe, since git is not a great place for big binary files.